# summing values by date range in google sheets when given in plain text

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet I'm referencing called 'data' which has 3 columns:

| Date | Desc | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/15/2023 | Some Insurance Co | 93.39 |
| 01/16/2023 | Insurance Co | 89.90 |
| 01/17/2023 | Some other expense | 17.99 |
| 02/03/2023 | Some Insurance Co | 95.96 |

I'm using this formula which returns 0 results:

```
=SUMIFS(data!C:C,data!A:A,">="&DATEVALUE("1/1/2023"),data!A:A,"<="&DATEVALUE("1/31/2023"))
```

Column A is in plain text and it's trimmed. Why do I get 0 results?

Comment: my only guess is if they are valid dates in Column A (click on the date(s) & calendar popup appears), just make sure both the dates in Column A & the dates used inside *datevalue* part of the formula use the same `dd/mm/yyyy` OR `mm/dd/yyyy` format (this depends on your sheet locale settings)

Comment: Thanks very much!  Turns out I had the right Locale settings for where I live, but the data I was importing had dates in a different format just as you suggested.  Thanks for the tip!